# Pass checkbox data to next activity

Tags: android, android-intent, checkbox

I am creating a list of items with a `listview` with `checkbox`. I want to pass the checked options to next `activity`.

For this I am using an **string array** for passing  the results to `other activity`. Everything is going fine but as I click on button to pass the data to next activity, Application halts with a `logcat` error of `NullPointerException`. It maybe a very simple concept but I am not known to it as I am a newbie to android.

Any help would be appreciated..

Java File..

```
package com.example.travelplanner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class TailoredtwoActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener{

    String[] builder;
    Button btn1;
    ListView mListView;
    String[] array = new String[] {"Ham", "Turkey", "Bread"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tailoredtwo);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, array);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewcity);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tailortwo_submit);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        SparseBooleanArray positions = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            if(positions.get(index)==true)
            {
                 builder[index] = array[index];
            }
        }
        Intent i1 = new Intent(this, TailoredthreeActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putStringArray("city", builder);
        i1.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(i1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

This is logcat:

```
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.travelplanner/com.example.travelplanner.TailoredthreeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047):    at com.example.travelplanner.TailoredthreeActivity.onCreate(TailoredthreeActivity.java:59)
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
07-12 10:48:49.686: E/AndroidRuntime(13047):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: please add onCreate method of TailoredthreeActivity, becouse there will be problem

Comment: i think you forget to initialize builder array

Comment: which line no - 59 indicate  of TailoredthreeActivity

Comment: what is written in TailoredthreeActivity.java: at line 59? paste the oncreate() method of TailoredthreeActivity.java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to use a arraylist to add items selected and pass the arraylist to the second activity

```
   checked = new ArrayList<String>();
   public void onClick(View view) {
        SparseBooleanArray positions = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            if(positions.get(index)==true)
            {
                 checked.add(array[index]);
            }
        }
        Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TailoredthreeActivity.class);
            i1.putStringArrayListExtra("list",checked);
        startActivity(i1);
    }
```

To receive

```
 ArrayList<String> getChecked;   
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null)
    {
      getChecked = extras.getStringArrayList("list");

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the array first because every array is an object in java

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        SparseBooleanArray positions = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
         builder= new String[array.length];
        for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            if(positions.get(index)==true)
            {
                 builder[index] = array[index];
            }
        }
```