# Selecting elements from listview

Tags: android

code looks like this:

```
array = delListView.getCheckedItemPositions();

    items = new ArrayList<String>();

    delBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
            {
                int pos = array.keyAt(i);

                    if (array.valueAt(i))
                    {
                        items.add(deleteAdapter.getItem(pos));
                    }           

                Log.e("selected", items.get(pos));
            }
```

In the activity if i check an item then uncheck it and check another one i get the following error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutofBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
```

Ultimately i am going to pass the resulting list to another activity.
What can i do?

Comment: similar one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608002/pass-checkbox-data-to-next-activity

Comment: items is apparently empty. what makes you think there is anything at all in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most likely, it's from your debug line,

```
Log.e("selected", items.get(pos));
```

what assurance do you have that `items` has an element at `pos`? from what i can see in the code, `items` is empty.

Comment: You were right about the debug line. My assurance is that when i just clicked an item the debug line showed it to me, but if i selected one more item it would just show the initial one twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think because of your condition :

```
if (array.valueAt(i))
{
   items.add(deleteAdapter.getItem(pos));                     
}
```

because of your if condition, if array.valueAt(i) not return true, value will not be added to Arraylist items. and when you are trying to get value at that index by Log.e("selected", items.get(pos)); It is crashing app.