# ListView item check

Tags: android, android-listview

What i have is basically a List, a List View with an adapter, a `sparcebooleanarray` and a Button. 
I am using `simple_list_item_multiple_choice` for the adapter.

This is what i`ve got so far but it just tells me which item is selected:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   int count = adapter.getCount();
   for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      if(array.get(i) == false) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "nothing is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } else if(array.get(i) == true) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "something is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   }
}
```

How can i check to see if none of the items in the list are selected?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608002/pass-checkbox-data-to-next-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a method which check if non of the item item is selected:

```
SparseBooleanArray array = mList.getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i=0; i<array.size(); i++) {
   if (array.valueAt(i)) {
      String item = mList.getAdapter().getItem(array.keyAt(i)).toString();
      Log.i(TAG,item + " was selected");
      return false;  //We found a selected item
   }
}
return true;  //We could not find any selected item
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that "array" is a SparceBooleanArray. On that foreach statement it says that it can iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable. How can i change that statement?

Answer (score 0):

`mListView.getCheckedItemPosition()` return the current selected item if your listview's choice mode is SINGLE.

`mListView.getCheckedItemPositions()` returns an array of selected checked items.

So in your case which is a multiple selection listview, this will work.